# Prevent type coercion when using string template formatting

Tags: python, python-2.x

```
>>> b'potato {} potato'.format(u'potato')  # return value matches the template 
'potato potato potato'
>>> b'potato %s potato' % u'potato'  # return value is coerced
u'potato potato potato'
```

In `str.format` the template controls the return type, but in `str.__mod__` the template gets 'promoted' to a unicode.

1. Is that documented / reliable behaviour?
2. How to do a percent-style substitution such that the return type is matching the template?

The obvious guess doesn't work:

```
>>> b'potato %b potato' % u'potato'
ValueError: unsupported format character 'b' (0x62) at index 8
```

I'm not interested in solutions which do type-checking and/or an explicit decode/encode call.  Ideally I want the templating to raise `UnicodeEncodeError` if the template variable is a unicode object and it can't be encoded to ascii.

Comment: Wow. Looks like unicode/bytes distinction is blurry and broken in Python 2. If only there were some version of Python out there where they had fixed this.... ;)

Comment: 1) Coercion happens with the `%s` conversion type, I'm pretty sure that's documented in the conversion table of the docs. 2) Doubt it :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is documented both in the start of the section [String Formatting Operations](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations) and in the conversion table, specifically, in the beginning of the section it is stated:

> Given `format % values` ... if format is a Unicode object, *or* if any of the objects being converted using the `%s` conversion are Unicode objects, the result will also be a Unicode object.

so that's a given.

A solution that doesn't involve `.encode` is unattainable from what I understand (and `repr`ing with `%r` isn't an option either). `str.__mod__` is a fast operation that doesn't handle much for you, `.format` has the <s>courtesy</s> audacity of calling `.encode` for you while also providing other goodies (hence why it exists).

Aside: if anyone was wandering, it is also documented in the specification of [PEP 3101](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/) that, for `.format`, the type of the format string will determine the outcome.